# Clipboard Copy is missing table header background when pasted in MS Excel

Tags: c#, clipboard

I am trying to use the Clipboard class to copy a table in html format. Everything is working fine and I can paste the content in MS Word and Outlook. But when I paste the content in MS Excel it is not copying the table header background color which was set in the html code. Below is my code for reference.

```
var htmlCode = $@"Version:1.0)
                        StartHTML:000125
                        EndHTML:000260
                        StartFragment:000209
                        EndFragment:000222
                        <html>
                            <head>
                            <style>
                            table, th, td {{
                              border: 1px solid black;
                              border-collapse: collapse;
                            }}
                            </style>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <th style=""background-color:#00559b"">Firstname</th>
                                <th style=""background-color:#00559b"">Lastname</th> 
                                <th style=""background-color:#00559b"">Age</th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td>
                                <td>50</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Eve</td>
                                <td>Jackson</td>
                                <td>94</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>80</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </body>
                            </html>";
            Clipboard.SetText(htmlCode, TextDataFormat.Html);
```

Below is a output screenshot from MS Word and MS Excel, notice the blue background is missing in the header for MS Excel.
[image: Screenshot of MS Word]

[image: Screenshot of MS Excel]